# Jenkins Pipeline project should update on scm change, but not auto-build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm  looking for the right instructions for a `Jenkinsfile` to *enable* SCM polling, but *disable* building after a SCM change.

I have a job that has to be run manually (uses *parameters*). When new parameters are added, the job should be updated. *However*, the job should not automatically run.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to update the job definition is to run it. You may need a "fake-run", manually or automatically. 
You could restrict the trigger to changes to the jenkinsfile exclusively (ignoring all other files changes), though it does not guarantee that these changes are ot the parameters specifically.
Anything more specific, you would need to create a separate job that runs automatically on the repo changes, that would analyze the changeset to determine whether changes to the job parameters are part of the changeset, and only if that is the case, then trigger a "fake-run" on your actual job.